# Nested flexboxes not wrapping in chrome or IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, flexbox

I have a few nested flexboxes that I want to use for a responsive website, and they work properly in firefox, but not in chrome or IE. The links should be able to wrap so that they are on top of one another when you make the screen smaller.

The links wrap properly here: http://jsfiddle.net/6796b/

But when they are in another flexbox they stop wrapping and overflow (Note: Only the green "links" aren't wrapping/stacking properly. Everything else works as intended.): **http://jsfiddle.net/3525C/8/**

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">logo</div>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="link">link one</div>
        <div class="link">link two</div>
        <div class="link">link three</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex; /* If I take this line out the links wrap properly again, but everything else breaks. */
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.logo {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.nav {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    background-color: lightgray;
    text-align: center;
}
.link {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to apply a `flex-shrink` value of `1` in order for the flex item to be flexible. See [edit 9](http://jsfiddle.net/3525C/9/).

The default being: `flex: 0 1 auto` which allows the flex item to "[shrink to its min-size when there is insufficient space](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-css-flexbox-1-20140325/#propdef-flex)"

In your case, setting `flex: 1 0 auto` allows `nav` to grow, but the `0` prevent it from being allowed to shrink, even in overflow situations (your case here with inline-blocks).

i.e. If you want 'everything' to wrap inside a flex container, set its flex items to `flex: auto;`

EDIT: Changed `flex: 1 1 auto;` for `flex: auto;` for compatibility concerns, due to `auto` being [possibly replaced by a 'main-size` keyword](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2014Jul/0008.html) in the near future.

Comment: Awesome! It works exactly how I wanted. Just found flexboxes today so they are still really confusing. I thought I had that right because when I put the "nav" by itself it worked. See http://jsfiddle.net/6796b/ no obligation, but why does that work on its own?

Comment: It works there because your container isn't flex. Flex can be very challenging... Before using it, be mindful of its [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) and possible fallbacks required for backward compatibility with older browsers.